# Heroku Rake task not running shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, heroku, rake

I have this Rake task that works locally:

```
namespace :backup_to_s3 do
  task run: :environment do
    puts "Started S3 backup"
    # create .pgpass so we don't have to enter the password
    entry = "#{ENV['RDS_DB_HOSTNAME']}:*:*:#{ENV['RDS_DB_SUPER_USERNAME']}:#{ENV['RDS_DB_SUPER_PASSWORD']}"
    `echo '#{entry}' > ~/.pgpass;
    chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass;
    bash backup_to_s3.sh`
    puts "Finished S3 backup"
  end
end
```

Notice that it makes a call to run a shell script. Here's that shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

backupTime=`date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M`
S3Bucket=$S3_BUCKET_NAME
RDSHostname=$RDS_DB_HOSTNAME
RDSUsername=$RDS_DB_SUPER_USERNAME
RDSDatabaseName=$RDS_DB_NAME

pg_dump -Fc ${RDSDatabaseName} -h ${RDSHostname} -U ${RDSUsername} --no-password | gzip -9 | \
s3cmd put - s3://${S3Bucket}/postgres.${RDSDatabaseName}.dump.${backupTime}.gz
```

Like I said this all works locally, and the `puts` logging statements work. On Heroku, the task runs, but the `puts` statements are executed immediately, seeming to indicate that the system calls and the shell script are not being run.

I'm confused as to why this isn't working!

**UPDATE 7/15**

I found that you can set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable and avoid creating the `.pgpass` file. The Rake task is still not executing the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't provide you with a traditional virtual private server, so I would not assume that you have access to write to the home directory. It's very likely that you might be getting a permission denied error when creating the `.pgpass` file.

Try placing your file in the relative `tmp/` directory of your rails project instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering Keith. That's what I thought the issue was at first, but I ran `heroku run bash` to get to a shell prompt, and ran my rake task with `rake backup_to_s3:run`. I then ran `cat ~/.pgpass` which gave the correct output, so it seems like it is writing the file correctly and it's lasting for at least the time I spend in that shell session.